# Crash happens when try to set or synchronize NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios

I have following function:

```
-(int) getCounter:(BOOL)isIncrease { 

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber *counter = [userDefaults valueForKey:kCounter];

    int intCounter;
    if (counter == nil){
       intCounter = 0;
    } else {
        intCounter = [counter intValue];
    }
    if (isIncrease ){
        intCounter++;
        [userDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intCounter] forKey:kCounter];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
    }        
   return intCounter;
}
```

It looks simple and clear.

However sometimes I get following Exception in Fabric:

```
#11. Crashed: com.my.app
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1866def70 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x187c1190c -[CFPrefsPlistSource synchronize] + 96
2  CoreFoundation                 0x187c36674 -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_requestNewData] + 88
3  CoreFoundation                 0x187cd80e8 __58-[_CFXPreferences appSynchronizeWithIdentifier:container:]_block_invoke + 36
4  CoreFoundation                 0x187c38ea4 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 268
5  CoreFoundation                 0x187c3876c normalizeQuintuplet + 360
6  CoreFoundation                 0x187c38d8c -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 104
7  CoreFoundation                 0x187cd8058 -[_CFXPreferences appSynchronizeWithIdentifier:container:] + 292
8  Foundation                     0x1886def90 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) synchronize] + 52
9  appApp                      0x1004b11a4 -[MyProg getCounter:] + 4300083620
10 appApp                      0x1004adb8c -[MyProg callServerWithEventName:value:withDictionary:isEvent:isNewAPI:] + 4300069772
11 appApp                      0x1004ab658 __42-[MyProg sendEvent:withValues:]_block_invoke + 4300060248
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b1e1bc _dispatch_client_callout + 16
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b2af94 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 576
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b37634 _dispatch_source_latch_and_call + 204
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b20160 _dispatch_source_invoke + 820
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b2c210 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 468
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b219a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b2c8d8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 360
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b2e34c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x186b2e0ac _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186d272a0 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x186d26d8c start_wqthread + 4
```

Take a look on line 9:

```
9  appApp                      0x1004b11a4 -[MyProg getCounter:] + 4300083620
```

Sometimes it fails on: `[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) synchronize]`
and sometimes on: `[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:]`

Can somebody explain why I get this crash and how to avoid it?

I use `UserDefaults` in many places of my code but crash happen in above mentioned function.

Any suggestions?

**[EDIT 1]**

```
// in init:
mBackgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.my.app", NULL);
```

The root function I call `getCounter`:

```
- (void) sendEvent{

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 
                (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), 
   mBackgroundQueue, 
^{                
    [self callServerWithEventName:eventName ...                                 
                   withDictionary:nil 
                          isEvent:YES 
                         isNewAPI:YES];
}
```

from `callServerWithEventName` I call `[self getCounter];`

**[EDIT 2]**

Crash happens on `setObject:forKey:]`

```
#14. Crashed: com.my.app
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x184d397bc dispatch_group_enter + 108
1  CoreFoundation                 0x185e27610 -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendFullyPreparedMessage:toConnection:settingValue:forKey:retryCount:] + 240
2  CoreFoundation                 0x185e27c48 -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendMessageSettingValue:forKey:] + 388
3  CoreFoundation                 0x185e26620 -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_setValues:forKeys:count:] + 864
4  CoreFoundation                 0x185ee72a8 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:removeValuesForKeys:count:] + 264
5  CoreFoundation                 0x185e4dafc -[CFPrefsSearchListSource alreadylocked_setValues:forKeys:count:] + 428
6  CoreFoundation                 0x185ee72a8 -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:removeValuesForKeys:count:] + 264
7  CoreFoundation                 0x185ee7444 -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 60
8  CoreFoundation                 0x185e505c0 __108-[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:]_block_invoke + 268
9  CoreFoundation                 0x185e4fe88 normalizeQuintuplet + 360
10 CoreFoundation                 0x185e504a8 -[_CFXPreferences(SearchListAdditions) withSearchListForIdentifier:container:cloudConfigurationURL:perform:] + 104
11 CoreFoundation                 0x185eece7c -[_CFXPreferences setValue:forKey:appIdentifier:container:configurationURL:] + 276
12 Foundation                     0x1868a4eb8 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 68
13  ifyApp                      0x1004a518c -[MyProg getCounter:] + 4300362124
14  ifyApp                      0x1004a1b8c -[MyProg callServerWithEventName:value:withDictionary:isEvent:isNewAPI:] + 4300348300
15  ifyApp                      0x10049f658 __42-[MyProg sendEvent:withValues:]_block_invoke + 4300338776
```

Thanks,

Comment: `setObject:` is a `NSUserDefaults` method

Comment: Yes, Sorry I forgot to notice it already in your question. Can you try retrieving the value by `objectForKey:` and let us know if it still crashes?

Comment: @iOSAppDev i have 1M of clients and it happens sometimes. As I know `NSUserDefaults` is a singleton and its really weird

Comment: What I am asking is: Does this project crash randomly when you debug it with XCode? If yes, Can you try retrieving the value by `objectForKey:`? If you are having this issue only in production build with few of your clients reporting a crash, you might have a very hard time finding the issue.

Comment: @iOSAppDev it crashes in Prod and I cannot reproduce it. Also I added thread from where I call `getCounter`.  `NSUserDefaults` manipulations I do from several threads

Comment: i am suspecting thread safe, could pls check related to NSUserdefault thread safe?because it is background in thread

Comment: Don't call synchronize. There is generally no need to do so. And why aren't you using `integerForKey` and `setIntegerForKey`. There is no need to mess around with `NSNumber`.

Comment: @karthikeyan `NSUserDefaults` has always been thread-safe.

Comment: May I know, minimum deployment target and the sdk you used for development? is it latest sdk?

Comment: `objectForKey` rather than `valueForKey`

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace shows your crash is occurring due to a locking conflict in `synchronize` as you are calling it too frequently. There is no need to call `synchronize` and removing the call should eliminate the issue.

You can simplify your code considerably by using `integerForKey` & `setIntegerForKey` rather than `objectForKey` (Or `valueForKey` which is incorrect) and `setObjectForKey`.

```
- (NSInteger) getCounter:(BOOL)isIncrease {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger counter = [defaults integerForKey:kCounter];

    if (isIncrease) {
        counter++;
        [defaults setIntegerForKey:kCounter];
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I would agree with the point that `synchronize` don't need to be called. But, I doubt that `integerForKey` & `setIntegerForKey` would server\ any purpose for resolving the crash.

Comment: No, the crash is happening due to the unnecessary calling of synchronize causing locking issues. I simply took the opportunity to show a solution that is simple and clear unlike the original code which is unnecessarily complicated and using incorrect calls.

Comment: +1 for the efforts, but are you sure about `synchronize` is making it crash. I mean it's production only and we don't have a way to test it first hand, other than re-submitting the App with changes.

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows it crashed due to a locking conflict in synchronize. Synchronize should be called rarely, if ever. Certainly not every time you update userDefaults. You should be able to reproduce the problem with a TestFlight build.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have 2 types of crash, like pointed in my question. It crashes on `synchronize` and on `setObject:forKey:`

Comment: What does the stack trace for that crash look like?

Comment: @Paulw11 posted EDIT2

Comment: It looks similar; locking and dispatch group related. Do you have an exception message to go with the stack trace?  Read the documentation for `synchronize` and you will see that there is no reason to call it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call 'getCounter' from background queue with delay and it could be nil when you try to set 'intCounter'

Comment: In that case, `[NSNumber numberWithInt:intCounter]` would be `1`... It would not crash at all, even if it's nil.

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks like the object was released and you are calling *getCounter* method anyway.
That's why it show this strange 9th line.

Comment: Added root method

Comment: I assume when you call [self getCounter] self does not exist.
Can you share the whole picture? Where you create instance of self? What is its visibility scope?

Comment: Its not problem of `self`. Take a look on stack trace. Crash happens inside `getCounter`